# Py4JJavaError java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/SeqOps after upgrading Spark from 3.2.1 to 3.3.2

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, migration, python-3.9

Below code worked on Python 3.8.10 and Spark 3.2.1, now I'm preparing code for new Spark 3.3.2 which works on Python 3.9.5.
 The exact code works both on Databricks cluster with 10.4 LTS (older Python and Spark) and 12.2 LTS (new Python and Spark), so the issue seems to be only locally.
Running below PySpark code on WSL Ubuntu-22.04
Python 3.9.5 (used in Databricks Runtime 12LTS)
Libraries versions:
py4j               0.10.9.5
pyspark            3.3.2

```
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.3.2
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.15, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_362
```

I also tried at the beginning with 4 different configs I used earlier - after commenting this out, it's still failing.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

conf = SparkConf()
# conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
# conf.set("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.13:2.2.0")
# conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
# conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Test").config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc, spark_session)
```

And crashes on following error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 14
      7 # conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "1")
      8 # conf.set("spark.jars.packages", "io.delta:delta-core_2.13:2.2.0")
      9 # conf.set("spark.sql.extensions", "io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension")
     10 # conf.set("spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog", "org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog")
     12 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
---> 14 spark_session = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("testTests").config(conf=conf).getOrCreate()
     16 sqlContext = SQLContext(sc, spark_session)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/test9.5_new/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/session.py:274, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    272     session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)
    273 else:
--> 274     getattr(
    275         getattr(session._jvm, "SparkSession$"), "MODULE$"
    276     ).applyModifiableSettings(session._jsparkSession, self._options)
    277 return session

File ~/.pyenv/versions/test9.5_new/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py:1321, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1315 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1316     self.command_header +\
   1317     args_command +\
   1318     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1320 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1321 return_value = get_return_value(
   1322     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1325     temp_arg._detach()

File ~/.pyenv/versions/test9.5_new/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py:190, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    188 def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    189     try:
--> 190         return f(*a, **kw)
    191     except Py4JJavaError as e:
    192         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File ~/.pyenv/versions/test9.5_new/lib/python3.9/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o58.applyModifiableSettings.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/SeqOps
    at io.delta.sql.parser.DeltaSqlParser.<init>(DeltaSqlParser.scala:72)
    at io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension.$anonfun$apply$1(DeltaSparkSessionExtension.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.$anonfun$buildParser$1(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:272)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:60)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized.foldLeft$(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:68)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foldLeft(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSessionExtensions.buildParser(SparkSessionExtensions.scala:271)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.sqlParser$lzycompute(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:138)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.sqlParser(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.BaseSessionStateBuilder.build(BaseSessionStateBuilder.scala:362)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.org$apache$spark$sql$SparkSession$$instantiateSessionState(SparkSession.scala:1175)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.$anonfun$sessionState$2(SparkSession.scala:162)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState$lzycompute(SparkSession.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.sessionState(SparkSession.scala:157)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.conf$lzycompute$1(SparkSession.scala:1069)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.conf$1(SparkSession.scala:1069)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$.applyModifiableSettings(SparkSession.scala:1072)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.collection.SeqOps
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 30 more
```

Comment: You should check the environment variables for pyspark and java_home and maybe for pythonpath as well

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved after the update of delta-core jar version from io.delta:delta-core_2.13:2.2.0 to io.delta:delta-core_2.12:2.2.0. Scala 2.12 is required for Spark 3.3.2.